# Why is my Windows "System.currentTimeMillis()" system time exactly 8 seconds behind all the other computers?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, time, timestamp

I am writing a real time networking program running on multiple computers and I decided to synchronize events using the OS system time. The problem is that one of my computers is 8000 ms behind the other two. The slow one is running Windows 7 and the other two that I am using for testing are running Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.04 respectively. How do I fix the OS system time on my Windows 7 computer?

Comment: Is the clock on the Windows 7 machine 8 seconds behind the other two?

Comment: Are you using the same ntp server for all 3 machines?

Comment: @JustinPearce "The slow one is running Windows 7"

Comment: As DavidPostill said, maybe configuring an identical NTP server for all machines would help. I would also force a sync once the NTP server is configured, so that i don't rely on some arbitrary schedule for the sync.

Comment: What happens if you manually reset the times on all the operating systems to the same time eg. 14:03:00. Does the Windows 7 time stay in sync or move to 8 seconds behind? You can change the time by double-click on the clock in the task tray on XP/7.